# Mongodb updating goes very slow on large collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database in mongodb with two collections. One collection has 1.4 billion documents and the other has 1.6 million. The total size of database is 150Gb. I run a code which I collect data form the collection with 1.4 billion and I update the collection with the 1.6 million. The hole operation takes up to 7 days. And in the begging of the process it was running fast, but as the time past the process begun very slow. Now the process updates 2-3 documents per second. The machine is a server with 256Gb of ram, in order to achieve fast readings, and has a ssd of 2Tb. The os is Ubuntu and the filestystem is ext4, which installed mistakenly rather than the xfs. What is the problem and the mongodb is so slow?

Below is the code that I am running from a Python script

```
import pymongo

#The connection achieved through ssh
client = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port)

db = client.slp

# This is a file with 1.4 unique billion records
with open('unique_pns.txt', 'r') as pns:
    publication_numbers = [pn.strip() for pn in pns.readlines()]

    for publication_number in publication_numbers:
        
        #Returns multiple documents
        results = db.annotations_inchi.find({"pn": publication_number})
        ls = []
        for result in results:
            ls.append(result['inchikey'])

        ls = list(set(ls))
        db.contents.update_one({"publication_number": publication_number}, { "$set": { "inchi_keys": ls } })
        print(count)
```

Comment: Are there indexes on the `pn` and `publication_number` fields? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: You may want to use [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) instead of doing the update per document. It can save you the RTT between the DB and your client.

Comment: You may want consider using `BulkWrite` operations for update. This will allow sending a single call to the database server with multiple updates - instead of one call per update with `updateOne`.

Comment: `update_one` is a "no-go" if you have many documents. Use Bulk update.